# dowpdown should display the selected value upon submission of form

Tags: javascript, python, html, drop-down-menu

I have three element on a form, three dropdown boxes, one which gets values from for "year" through database, and a dropdown which gets values from for "month" through database, and a third textbox which is day dropdown.
 What I want is that when I select any value from the dropdown box and submits the form the selected value disappears from the dropdown textbox and the first value of dropdown list appears.

I want that the dowpdown should display the selected value upon submission of form.

Below is the code which is written in html and JS also front end as python:

```
<label class="labels">Year 1:</label>

<select name='year1' id='year1' onchange ="chng_func(this.value,{{col_list}})" >
             %for item in year_lst:
    <option value="{{ item }}" selected=selected>{{ item }}</option>
     %end
 </select>

<label class="labels">Month 1:</label>

<select name = 'month1' id='month1' onchange="monthFunc()">
    %for item in month_lst:
    <option value="{{ item }}" >{{ item }}</option>
    %end 
</select>                       

<label class="labels">Day 1:</label>

<select name = 'day1' id='day1'>
    <script>
            monthFunc();
        </script>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What template engine are you using for html rendering? Jinja, Django, Mako? This will help us to help you.
But in general you need to take submitted values and *put them back* into the html. This means that you need to write a logic inside your for loops to check if submitted value is matching with loop iterated value.
I don't know exactly what the syntax of this template engine, but it'll looks like this:

```
%for item in year_lst:
<option value="{{ item }}" %if item=submitted_item: selected=selected %end >{{ item }}</option>
%end
```

So during iteration you need to check what exact option should be selected.
Give me more info in case you need to get more help.

@UPDATE

So we've clarified that you're using Bottle framework and I think, you're using [SimpleTemplate Engine](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#simpletemplate-engine) for html rendering (it's obvious from the code snippet you've posted).

Here's what you need to do to have selected values for year/month/day controls after form submission.
You can read about form submission handling in [this section](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#html-form-handling).

So let us consider that your form submit method is http POST:

```
<form method=POST ...>
</form>
```

In this case for handling the submitted values you need to have following route handler on server side:

```
# this route will serve your form POST submission
@route('/your_route', method='POST')
def route_handler():

    # here you're reading selected values from request
    year1 = request.forms.get('year1')
    month1 = request.forms.get('month1')
    day1 = request.forms.get('day1')

    # and here you're setting that values back to the template to write a logic html side
    return template('your_template', year1=year1, month1=month1, day1=day1)
```

And finally your html should looks something like this:

```
<select name='year1' id='year1' onchange ="chng_func(this.value,{col_list}})" >
    %for item in year_lst:
    <option value="{{ item }}" {{ "selected=selected" if item = year1 else "" }}>{{ item }}</option>
    %end
</select>
```

Let's see what does this part do: `{{ "selected=selected" if item = year1 else "" }}`. Basically it means that if our looping value **item** is equal to submitted value **year1**, then output the **"selected=selected"** text to html, which will make the selected year option to be rendered as selected. You can read about inline expressions [here](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/stpl.html#inline-expressions).

And you need to change the month and day selections accordingly.
That's it, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Template engine is Jinja @Hett

Comment: Hmm...have you changed the syntax configuration? Cause I don't remember %for: %end syntax in jinja.
Here's what I think you need to do:

{% for item in year_lst %}
<option value="{{ item }}" {% if item=submitted_item %} selected=selected {% endif %} >{{ item }}</option>
{% endfor %}

Although you need to pass the submitted value back to template engine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate and tell me what do you mean by pass the submitted value back to template engine?? Sorry I am so new to this !

Comment: I need you to answer one more question before giving the complete answer. What python web framework are you using? Flask, bottle, wheezy.web or other?

Comment: Hey, @UserAR, have you solved your problem? Is there anything else I can help?

Comment: What if I want to do the same using Django?? @Hett